# How to shorten the usage of one image source retrieved via php codes

Tags: php, wordpress

newbie here. I'm using the following code to extract the secondary image source of my wordpress posts, but I think I could shorten it someway...

Here is the code I'm currently using inside `img src=""`

```
<?php $images = get_attached_media('image'); $featured_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { unset($images[ $featured_image_id ] ); } $harukunt = wp_get_attachment_image_src( key($images),'large'); echo '' . $harukunt[0] . ''; ;?>
```

Maybe I could simplify this by defining some values in the header.php file, so then I can call the image in a shorter way in the posts?

```
<?php
$images = get_attached_media('image');
$featured_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
if ( has_post_thumbnail()
)
{ unset($images[ $featured_image_id ] );
}
$harukunt = wp_get_attachment_image_src( key($images),'large');
echo '' . $harukunt[0] . '';
;
?>
```

And then call the image on posts by simply using `img src="<?php harukunt("$post->ID"); ?>"` or something. But it isnt working this way, due to my poor knownledge.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Return #Return
(WP_Post[]) Array of media attached to the given post. Im not in front a pc, but i'm pressuming the index isn't the ID of post. Do a var dump on the function.

Comment: This feels like a perfect candidate for code to be wrapped in a function. I’d even have the function output the full HTML and then in your template you can just use `maybe_get_secondary_image()`, or whatever you want to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function and add it to your functions.php file like this:

```
function get_secondary_img($post_id, $print = true ){
    if(has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) {
        $attachments = get_attached_media('image',$post_id);
        if(count($attachments) < 2){
            $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
        } else {
            foreach($attachments as $key => $attachment){
                if($key !== get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id)){
                    $attachment_id = $key;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if($attachment_id){
            $attachment = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id,'large');
            $src = $attachment[0];
            $width = $attachment[1];
            $height = $attachment[2];
            $alt = get_post_meta($attachment_id,'_wp_attachment_image_alt',true);
            if($print == true){
                echo '<img width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" src="'.$src.'" alt="'.$alt.'" />';
            } else {
                return $src;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you want to output the html for the image you can just do

```
<?php echo get_secondary_img( $post_id ); ?>
```

Or if you want to just return the src attribute, you can just do

```
$yourvariable = get_secondary_img( $post_id, false );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but there's something missing in the code you provided. This is currently providing me the main picture (the featured one). While with my code I was retrieving the secondary one, which I need. Maybe you need to add something in the code to exclude featured img.

Comment: The following function.php code should do the job (but i dont know how to return the src attribute :"D) >>>

Comment: function haruki($post_id){global$post;$thumbnail_ID=get_post_thumbnail_id();$images=get_children(array('post_parent'=>$post_id,'post_status'=>'inherit','post_type'=>'attachment','post_mime_type'=>'image','order'=>'ASC','orderby'=>'menu_orderID'));if($images):foreach($imagesas$attachment_id=>$image):if($image->ID!=$thumbnail_ID):$img_alt=get_post_meta($attachment_id,'_wp_attachment_image_alt',true);//altif($img_alt==''):$img_alt=$image->post_title;endif;

Comment: $big_array=image_downsize($image->ID,'large');$img_url=$big_array[0];echo$img_url;endif;endforeach;endif;}

Comment: @D. Dragon, sorry, I misunderstood the question, by "secondary image", I thought you meant the second from largest size of the "featured-image".... give me a minute and I will update the function.

Comment: @D. Dragon, I have updated the answer to get the second image, if a second does not exist, it will get the featured image.

Comment: @D. Dragon, no problem, can you give the answer an upvote for me?