# How to return the SRC attribute of my secondary image via php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following code in wordpress functions.php file in order to retrieve my secondary image (the non-featured one).

```
function haruki($post_id) {
global $post;
$thumbnail_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$images = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID') );
if ($images) :
foreach ($images as $attachment_id => $image) :
if ( $image->ID != $thumbnail_ID ) :
$img_alt = get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); //alt
if ($img_alt == '') : $img_alt = $image->post_title; endif;
$big_array = image_downsize( $image->ID, 'large' );
$img_url = $big_array[0];
echo $img_url;
endif; endforeach; endif; }
```

Then when I want to output the html for the image I do:

```
<?php haruki("$post->ID"); ?>
```

Now I would like to just return the src attribute, but I'm failing by doing this:

```
$myvariable = haruki( $post_id, false );
```

How am I supposed to fix this last one in order to make it work correctly?

Comment: By actually using `return` inside your function, instead of `echo` ...

Comment: Do yourself, and everyone who you ask for help, a favour, and get into the habit of indenting your code to reflect its structure (e.g. each the contents of each loop and if should be indented one level further than its parent).

Comment: @CBroe not really.

Comment: @IMSoP the problem is I haven't composed this code myself, I'm newbie and have no idea about its structure, hence that's why I'm asking here how to use :-)

Comment: Yes, really. Don't give such responses, please, that isn't helping at all. If you tried anything in that regard, then _show us_ that, then we can probably tell you what you did actually wrong. What sense is a call like `haruki( $post_id, false )` currently supposed to make, when your function doesn't even take a second parameter?

Comment: @CBroe sorry I didn't mean to be offensive. "not really" I mean I tried your suggestion (switching return instead of echo, in the function, but it just caused a blank output result). I have no idea what sense is calling it like  haruki( $post_id, false ), I'm just trying to emulate one code that I found and works fine but retrieving a different image (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69863149/how-to-shorten-the-usage-of-one-image-source-retrieved-via-php-codes#comment123494788_69863149) you can read the post answer and the comments under it.

Comment: If you're interested in learning, I suggest you have a look around for an introductory PHP programming course. To get value out of this site you really need to understand some basics so that you can frame a specific question. If you just need some changes to this code, you're probably better off finding a site where you can pay someone a small amount to make them.

Comment: _"I'm just trying to emulate one code that I found"_ - and you did not notice that the function there explicitly takes a second parameter? `function get_secondary_img($post_id, $print = true )` And how it uses that to decide whether to echo or return, you can also directly see there.

Comment: I updated the answer on the post you created with the exact same question a few days ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to shorten the usage of one image source retrieved via php codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69863149/how-to-shorten-the-usage-of-one-image-source-retrieved-via-php-codes)